# Can I make PSTextFieldSpecifier be read-only

Tags: iphone, settings, readonly

Is there any way I could force **PSTextFieldSpecifier be read-only** in iPhone Settings view?

It has auto-scaling font size, center justification and without title looks just perfect for copyright notice. The problem is that it's editable text. Even when if I would reset value each time app starts up, it's still pretty not-too-nice behaviour.

Backup plan: use two PSTitleValueSpecifiers... just not sure if copyright notice is valid, when it's spread over two bold titles and two non-bold values. But that's a different question.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to display a readonly textfield you can use **PSTitleValueSpecifier**

Comment: Well, like it says in question the PSTitleValueSpecifier is my backup plan. Any other ideas?